# HighStock if time inertval missing shows red line or blank space?

Tags: highcharts

Hi I used high stock chart for showing data in time series format. I received data every 5 minutes, for X-axis I set timestamp which I received on every 5 minutes. but in case some data not coming from 5 minutes then I want to display that line in `red` or `blank` below I tried

[JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/yogesh_0586/x68casgx/2/)

In this demo data come at 10:25 and after 10:35 so in between I want to shows red line or blank space. Following images shows expected output

[image]

```
Or
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue here is how is highcharts supposed to know that there is no data at 10:30? Your data timestamp intervals are not identical (meaning they don't occur every 5 minutes).

What you could do is put a watcher function in place that gets the data first. Inside of this put a timer that if 5 minutes go by without any data being retrieved, send out a data point like `[<the time stamp>, null]`. Now, you will also need to a property to not link null points called [`connectNulls`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.connectNulls). This is false by default so your 2nd option above is satisfied (see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x68casgx/3/)).

For option 1 (the red line) you would need to create a new series containing the previous point and the next point surrounding your no-data point and set its series color to red. The drawback here is that if you have many cases with data gaps you will be creating many 2 point series. An example series to add would be:

```
{
    color: 'red',
    showInLegend: false,
    data: [
    [1415787839488, 0.5590000152587891],
    [1415788494848, 0.5139999985694885]
        ]
}
```

And an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x68casgx/5/).

Comment: for first fiddle case you inserted this `[1415788167168,null]` but is possible this without using `null` or something I searched `gapSize`

Comment: @yogesh Yes, you can use gapSize if you use a stock chart type of chart.