# Creating gaps in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a master-detail chart that displays several series of values against timestamps in line, spline and column formats, depending on the user's choice.

[image]

My issue is that when a range of timestamps (say a whole week) and their corresponding values are missing, the spline, line and master do what is expected and plot a smooth line between the gap. However this is misleading and I would rather it show a break in the line once a given range of timestamps are missed. I have tried `connectNulls: false` but as both the timestamps and values are missing this does not work.

Is there any way to achieve this? Preferably without looping through the data and adding the missing timestamps and null values, as the intervals are not always regular.

Comment: How does one know it is missing if the intervals are not regular, and no nulls are added?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27251912/highstock-if-time-inertval-missing-shows-red-line-or-blank-space/27252357#27252357. You basically need to set a threshold where if there is no data you then add nulls.

Comment: Better is using Highstock and then set [ordinal](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal) as false.

Comment: Thank you @SebastianBochan - Highstock seems to be a lot better suited to this application.

Comment: @SebastianBochan: updated link to [ordinal](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal). However, the general question remains - how do you define gaps of custom size, such that, for example, points 0, 1, and 2 are connected in a line chart, and 3, 4, and 5 are separately connected, no matter what the gap size is between point #2 and point #3.